# RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined Forge App

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am building a 3-legged OAuth Forge application using Visual Studio Code and Node.js. Once I start debugging, the server is listening on http://localhost:3000, but after signing in, I am getting this error message and cannot see Forge Viewer. What is the reason?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPjXd.png)

Comment: Please provide more information. What source code are you using? Is it one of the official Forge samples, and if so, which one? Or, if it's a custom code of your own, consider sharing it here, at least the parts related to authentication.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're seeing is most likely a "side effect" of another issue in your code. It looks like the server code is failing for some reason, and when the server tries to send back the generic error response to the client, it does not know what **status code** to include in the response.

Consider stepping through the authentication code in your Node.js server to narrow down the actual code that's causing the issue.